# How to include a labelled item only if referenced?

Tags: cross-referencing

In the text, I have some `\ref{a}...`

At the end, I have a list of

```
\item first \label{a}
...
\item last \label{z}
```

I want to show only the first item. I tried defining a custom ref such that it also defines a variable and ref, like so:

```
mycustomref[1] -> \newcommand{#1} \ref{#1}

mycustomlabel -> if a is defined, show the item a
```

But it turns out `\newcommand{#1}` is not valid, as it literally interprets it as #1. Thanks so much.

Comment: `\newcommand{#1}` is no valid syntax of course. If understand your question correctly, you need a test whether a label is referred to already and then show the content, otherwise hide it.

Comment: Yes! I couldn't find custom package for it

Comment: Do you not want to show \ref{z} because it is undefined, or because you have never used \ref{z} before?  If the former, you can use `\@ifundefined{r@#1}{...}{...}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a `\@namedef` each time `\mycustomref` is used and a wrapper for `\item`, checking whether the name is already used.

However, this does work this way only if the reference is done in advance, i.e. before the custom item macro is applied.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycustomref}[1]{%
  \@namedef{referred::#1}{#1}%
  \ref{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\mycustomitem}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{referred::#2}{%
  }{\item #1 \label{#2}}
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

See \mycustomref{foo} %but also \mycustomref{foobar}

\begin{enumerate}
  \mycustomitem{Foo}{foo}
  \mycustomitem{Foobar}{foobar}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This will also fail, if none of the items is referred to as well → the `enumerate` environment will complain then